# Getting user to send more than one picture during their session

Tags: php, session

I had created a database named creativemedia with two tables in it (images and userinformation). I'm trying to create a page where users upload images and view them on them on the same page. The user should be able to keep inserting images but one at a time. The issue that i'm having is that after 1 image has been successful inserted, i cannot submit a second image as it just echos an inbuilt error message. Here is all the code that i used to send images:

Top of the page:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION['username'] AND (!$_SESSION['user_id'])) {
header("location: index.php");
}
?>
```

Main body:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("creativemedia");

        if(isset($_POST['Upload'])) { 
        $allowedExts = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png", "JPG");
        $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
        $extension = end($temp);

        if ((($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
        || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/JPG")
        || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
        || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/png"))
        && ($_FILES["image"]["size"] < 500000000)
        && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
          {
          if ($_FILES["image"]["error"] > 0)
            {
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["image"]["error"] . "<br>";
            }
          else
            {
            if (file_exists("Images Upload/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]))
              {
              echo "<script>alert('This file already exists, please insert a different image')</script>";
              }
            else
              {
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "Images Upload/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"])){
                    $target= "Images Upload/".$_FILES["image"]["name"];
                    $sessionid= $_SESSION['user_id'];

                    $query= "insert into images(UserID, Image) values('$sessionid','$target')";

                    if(mysql_query($query)){
                        echo"<script>alert('Upload Successful!')</script>";
                        }
                        else{echo "this isn't sending the information";}

                    }
                    else{echo "this isn't working";}
              }
            }
          }
        else
          {
          echo"<script>alert('Please select an image!')</script>";
          }
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Sidenote: `&&` has precedence over `AND`

Comment: We also need to see your HTML form.

Comment: I see a lot of if, else, else, else... why not if, else if, else if, else?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you put [] after your file name 'image' in your html code.  Use for loop to submit each of those images.  Hope this helps.

Comment: He's not doing a while loop. He's refreshing the page after upload. I think the issue may be that the file names are the same so there is an overwrite issue. He needs to randomize the name with maybe $filename=md5($username.$date)

Comment: And I mean the date(U) function. So every second you'll get a different number.

Comment: Agree.. I think the user must be specific whether he is uploading multiple images with single file button at once or different images with multiple file buttons

Comment: A `foreach` loop is required when uploading multiple files (*at the same time*). If the user is to upload only one file at a time, then using `name="file[]"` won't help. Read the question over again. *"The issue that i'm having is that after 1 image has been successful inserted, i cannot submit a second image as it just echos an inbuilt error message."*

Comment: Well a session user must be able to insert as many images as they want, however i've only allowed them to insert one image at a time. The problem is that a session user can only send one picture, ever. So even if they log out and then back in again, they wont be able to insert another image. What i'm trying to find out is that, how can i make it that a session user can keep inserting images one after another without any issues. Thanks.

Comment: @Fred-ii-if that comment addressed me, It said to put [] first and then a for loop to submit each of them...

Answer (score 0):

Here are the major things to be kept in mind for multiple file upload.  YOu know most of them, can go through to identify where your code missed out.

1. enctype is a must
2. [] is a must
3. For loop or foreach loop to submit one image after the other, note the addition of $i after ur posted code.

   for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['image']['name']); $i++) {

   //your code for mime types etc.

   $target= "Images Upload/".$_FILES["image"]["name"][$i];

   //insert query

   }

Sessions are not a compulsory to upload images.  I am not sure if there was any specific reason to use them in your code.